# Ramsey's infinite principle and the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Frank Plumpton Ramsey, best known for giving his name to Ramsey Theory, presented the following theorem in [On a Problem of Formal Logic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/BLOGPAPERS/ramseyorig.pdf), that was submitted in 1928 and published posthumously.

*Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite class, and $\mu$ and $r$ positive integers ; and let all those sub-classes of $\Gamma$ which have exactly $r$ members, or, as we may say, let all $r$-combinations of the members of $\Gamma$ be divided in any manner into $\mu$ mutually exclusive classes $C_i$ $(i = l, 2, \ldots, \mu)$, so that every $r$-combination is a member of one and only one $C_i$; then, assuming the axiom of selections, $\Gamma$ must contain an infinite sub-class $\Delta$ such that all the $r$-combinations of the members of $\Delta$ belong to the same $C_i$.*

I understand that the "axiom of selections" is the Axiom of Choice (AC).

My questions are: Does this really require AC? Is it equivalent to AC or can it be proved using something weaker than AC?

Comment: Since the wording is "infinite", then, yes, we do need a modicum of choice. But once you realise this can be proved for countable sets by hand, without choice, and the statement is just about "infinite classes", it is easy to see that the whole thing just follows from "Every infinite set has a countable subset", which is weaker than countable choice even.

Comment: See MR0255389 (41 #51) 
Kleinberg, E. M.
The independence of Ramsey's theory.
J. Symbolic Logic 34 (1969), 205–206 and (self-promotion) MR0465865 (57 #5751) 
Blass, Andreas
Ramsey's theorem in the hierarchy of choice principles.
J. Symbolic Logic 42 (1977), no. 3, 387–390.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's perfect, thanks. If you want the big green tick, write it as an answer.  Asaf, thanks for your comment too.